# Cannot set dynamic height based on text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a textview within which is a label. The label gets texts of varying lengths from the server.

Now the texts from the server are displayed like so on my label (which is in a textview)

[image]

In order to increase the textview height as per the text in the label, I did this...

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
     incidentTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    incidentTextView.sizeToFit()


    actionTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    actionTextView.sizeToFit()

    submitByTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    submitByTextView.sizeToFit()
 }
```

But this gives me the result as shown below..

[image]

How can I align the fields like the first image and yet have the height of the textview increased dynamically as per the text in the label..?

**EDIT 1:** I cannot see the scrolling option also for UIView..

[image]

Comment: disable scrolling in incidentTextView

Comment: @Moayad Al kouz When I tap on the view, in the'attributes inspector', I don't see any option for scrolling..

Comment: select textView then you should find Scrolling enabled check box or you can disable scrolling by code  incidentTextView.isScrollEnabled = false

Comment: You have to set the vertical compression lower than the horizontal one

Comment: @CZ54 You mean the content compression resistance priority..?

Comment: It didn't work @CZ54

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz I have attached a screenshot also in the EDIT above which shows the scrolling option for a view is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UILabel` instead `UITextView` and just set `numberOfLines = 0`.

Make sure you used correct constraints to align UILable proper.

Comment: But to meet the design requirement of a gray background, I have to use a UITextview